# Мобильные игры в 2019

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-games

Выбираю книгу для того чтобы научиться создавать игры на телефоны и планшеты.
Заинтересовала книга "Программирование игр для Андроид" (Марио Цехнер)/
Но эта книга 2013 года.
Актуальна ли она сейчас, в 2019? Если нет, посоветуйте более актуальные книги.
Уточню, вопрос именно в том, чтобы подсказали книги и ресурсы, направленные на обучения созданию игр на мобилы, а не просто программирование для Андроид.
Не устарела ли книга Марио Цехнера?
Тем более сейчас появились Retina экраны и тд...

Comment: Вам стоит с чего либо вообще начать, первая ссылка выше, вторая отсюда: https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=159318. В первую очередь нужно начать понимать как это всё варится. По сути все книги отстают от развития на пару лет.